# How can I restart an Oracle database?

Tags: database, oracle, restart

I have to restart my Oracle database because of view changes in the SPFile. I tried to shutdown and startup, but I don't know how to startup in the right way again.

Comment: Just write in Google: How can i restart a Oracle Database.

Comment: better show your research effort

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Start SQL*Plus without connecting to a database

```
SQLPLUS /NOLOG
Connect as SYSDBA
CONNECT username AS SYSDBA
```

Issue the startup command

```
STARTUP
```

If that doesn't work for you I would recommend consulting the Oracle Docs on [starting up a DB](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/start001.htm). Lots of startup options are listed there.